# Enable a timer after download

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, ashx

This question may be asked a lot times. But i didn't find an exact solution for this, that is why i am asking it.

We are working in a project, where it got an update process. There is download functionality to download an exe.
We are using a handler to download the file. Its code is given below

### .ashx

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);    
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/exe";
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
context.Response.TransmitFile(fileUrl);
```

So we are calling this handler on a button click like:

### Click event

```
Response.Redirect("Test.ashx?fileUrl=" + downloadUrl, false);
```

Then its downloading the file.

Now we got a timer in our page. After download i want to enable that timer. How can i do this after the download. When i am giving it just below the Redirect like Timer1.Enabled= true; its not working. Can anyone please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: try, Timer1.Enabled= true; just above Response.Redirect("Test.ashx?fileUrl=" + downloadUrl, false);

Comment: @user970349: yes.. i tried that too... its not working.. i think because we are clearing the response content at the top of the handler..

Comment: @user970349: k .. but i think this is a common problem.. and someone will have a solution ? dont know..

Answer (score 1):

Use an iframe in the page and set its src to another .aspx page and put your download code in that aspx page. Before or after setting src enable timer.